# Queue multiple AirPlay inputs to a speaker with iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, airplay

I need to get signals from airplay enabled speakers or Apple TV regarding already it is playing and when the song finishes. I need to queue the multiple input signals to the speaker and also needs to play one by one according to priority. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researches I reached into a conclusion that it is not at all possible with iOS sdk.